# PHP how to check if product exists in cart

Tags: php

Before add it to cart i want to check if that item already exist. If item exist i dont want twice to show the some item in looping. Just increment quantity of existing item in array session.

**Session array with items in cart:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [qty] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [qty] => 1
        )
)
```

On `Cart` page where am looping items form cart i have this:

```
<?php
    $db = require('database.php');
    $cart_items = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : null;
    $products = array();

    if($cart_items):

        foreach ($cart_items as $key => $value)
        {
            $products[$key] = $value;

            $id = (int) $value['id'];
            $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=$id");

            while($row = $result->fetch_object())
            {
                $products[$key]['id'] = $row->id;
                $products[$key]['name'] = $row->name;
                $products[$key]['price'] = number_format($row->price, 2);

                 // check if item exists
                 // this dont work i dont know how to check this 
                if($id == $row->id && $value['qty'] == 1)
                {
                    $products[$key]['qty']++;
                }
            }
        }
    endif;
?>
```

**And fronted part where i loop cart products:**

```
<tbody>
             <?php if($products): ?>
                 <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>

                     <tr>
                         <td><?= $product['id'];?></td>
                         <td><?= $product['name'];?></td>
                         <td><?= $product['price'];?> Eur</td>
                         <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="<?= $product['qty']; ?>" size="5"> </td>
                         <td><a href="<?= SITE_URL;?>?page=cart&action=delete&id=<?= $product['id'];?>" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</a> </td>
                     </tr>

                 <?php endforeach; ?>
             <?php endif;?>
</tbody>
```

So problem is when i click 2 times on item with `id` = 1 i get two new table rows with the some products. My idea is when i click 2 times on product `id = 1` just increment quantity on existing product in cart.

Any sugestion for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function to get all the existing product ids from the `$products` array. And then check whether the particular item exists in the `$products` array or not, and update the product and/or quantity details accordingly.

So your `while()` loop should be like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    $ids = array_column($products, 'id');
    if(in_array($row->id, $ids)){
        $products[$key]['qty']++;
    }else{
        $products[$key]['id'] = $row->id;
        $products[$key]['name'] = $row->name;
        $products[$key]['price'] = number_format($row->price, 2);
        $products[$key]['qty'] = 1;
    }
}
```

Also, remove this statement from your `foreach` loop,

```
$products[$key] = $value;
```

#### Updated:

From [**OP's comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704785/php-how-to-check-if-product-exists-in-cart/41704993?noredirect=1#comment70607097_41704993),

> Now problem is in looping products in cart, when i loop products in cart i have duplicate product becouse i add one product 2 times and update quantity. How to prevent double looping one item in cart! If i press 10 times product with id = 1. I dont want 10 new loop items in list i want only update quantity value. Prevent the some item loop in `<tr><td> ...</td></tr> ...`

Change your code inside the `if` block in the following way,

```
$unique_ids = array_unique(array_column($cart_items, 'id'));
foreach ($cart_items as $key => $value){
    if(!in_array($value['id'], $unique_ids)) continue;
    $id = (int) $value['id'];
    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=$id");

    while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        $ids = array_column($products, 'id');
        if(in_array($row->id, $ids)){
            $products[$key]['qty']++;
        }else{
            $products[$key]['id'] = $row->id;
            $products[$key]['name'] = $row->name;
            $products[$key]['price'] = number_format($row->price, 2);
            $products[$key]['qty'] = 1;
        }
    }
    $key = array_search($value['id'],$unique_ids);
    unset($unique_ids[$key]);
}
```

Comment: This work good and thanks for sugestion `array_column()`. What about prevent double row looping in `foreach`?

Comment: @Ivan Can you please elaborate what do you mean by *double row looping in foreach*?

Comment: Sorry i dont slove... When i loop cart products i have the some products in list. How avoid that

Comment: Nope, sorry for bad english. If i add item to cart i get in foreach only one item in loop. If i add again the some item in cart i get just want to update quantity "code above slove that problem what you give me". Now problem is in looping products in cart, when i loop products in cart i have duplicate product becouse i add one product 2 times and update quantity. How to prevent double looping one item in cart! If i press 10 times product with id = 1. I dont want 10 new loop items in list  i want only update quantity value. Prevent the some item loop in `<tr><td> ...</td></tr>` ...

Comment: @Ivan I've updated my answer. Please see the **Updated** section of my answer.